# Emscripten JS library - pass strings

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, emscripten

I want to interchange strings between C++ and JS in an Emscripten library.

What I did was in the C++ code:

```
extern "C" {
    // pass a string to JS, return a JS string back to C++
    const char* CallJavascript(const char* strInput) {
        static char outp[2048]; // static buffer for the return value.
        strncpy(outp, strInput, 2047); // copy input to the buffer
        
        glb_emscripten_call(pBuffer); // pass buffer and overwrite in JS. See below
        return outp; // return contents of changed buffer
    }
}
```

And in the JS file, that links with --js-library:

```
var LibraryGLB = {
  $GLB__deps: ['$Browser'],
  $GLB : {
    
    // pass a string pointer (char ** ), read what it passed and overwrite the string with
    // the return value.
    glb_emscripten_call:function( ioStringPointer )
    {
        var myString = HowToGetAString(ioStringPointer); // TODO
        alert(myString);
        var strOut = 'Hello World';
        strcpy(strOut, ioStringPointer, 2048); // TODO
    },


    end_of_struct:0
};

autoAddDeps(LibraryGLB, '$GLB');
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, LibraryGLB);
```

So, my 2 problems are: How to convert the C pointer address into a JS string, and how to copy the JS string's bytes to the pointer?
I wanted to use stringToUTF8() and tried to add `import Module from './myapp.js'`, but I got an SyntaxError "Cannot use import statement outside a module". Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, by accessing the HEAPU8 object:

```
    glb_emscripten_call:function( ioStringPointer )
    {
        // Read the string from the pointer
        var str = '';
        for(var i = 0; i<10; ++i){
            var ascii = HEAPU8[ioStringPointer + i];
            if(ascii == 0){break;}
            str += String.fromCharCode(ascii);
        }
        // Overwrite the string at that pointer (must have allocated enough memory)
        str = 'KungFu';
        for(var i = 0; i<str.length; ++i){
            HEAPU8[ioStringPointer + i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        HEAPU8[ioStringPointer + str.length] = 0;
    }
```